# iOS 5.1.1 Popover not dismissing automatically

Tags: ios, ipad, viewcontroller, popover

My application works well on older OS' but on 5.1.1 (tested on both iPad2 and new iPad) popover shows up, runs well but does not dismiss when user taps outside the popover. I do not use any dismissal code or buttons. I used iOS 5.0 SDK, XCode 4.2 to compile the app. Here's how I show it up. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
- (void)showNotifications {

    NotificationsViewController *vc = [[[NotificationsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    if ([UIApplication isIPad]) {

        vc.modalInPopover = YES;
        self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc] autorelease];

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:bottomView.frame inView:[bottomView superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    }
    else
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved. Just commented out the line

```
//vc.modalInPopover = YES; must be no on iOS 5
```

ModalInPopover must be false on iOS 5. Don't know if it still works on iOS 4 though.